# LessCSS: Nesting functions within concatenated classes

Tags: css, nested, less, rules, mixins

I'm having real issues with getting LessCSS to process a file that has a series of nested rules using the "&" concatenation selectors.

For example, the following will work without errors:

```
.grey-table {
    background: #EDEDED;
    tr {
        th {
            background: #DEDEDE;
        }
        td {
            color: #888;
        }
        &:nth-child(odd) {
            td {
                background-color: #F9FCFF;
            }
        }
        &:nth-child(even) {
            td {
                background-color: #EDF5FF;
            }
        }
        &:hover {
            td {
                background-color: #DFEAF9;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

However if I change the colours to be a function (of any sort - predefined or mixin), I get the error

"*Syntax Error on line 12 - undefined*"

```
 .grey-table {
    background: desaturate(#EDEDED, 100%);
    tr {
        th {
            background: desaturate(#DEDEDE, 100%);
        }
        td {
            color: desaturate(#888, 100%);
        }
        &:nth-child(odd) {
            td {
                background-color: desaturate(#F9FCFF, 100%); <------ Line 12
            }
        }
        &:nth-child(even) {
            td {
                background-color: desaturate(#EDF5FF, 100%);
            }
        }
        &:hover {
            td {
                background-color: desaturate(#DFEAF9, 100%);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I cannot find any reference material on this but I'm sure I can't be the only one?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot and had not noticed the tab on line 12 after the colon.

That's what was causing the error, but only when there was a less css mixin/variable. Apologies to all.

Answer (score 3):

i usually define the colors first and then call them in the functions:

```
@mycolor: #F9FCFF;
desaturate(@mycolor, 100%);
```

I am sorry, but there are no errors with your code on the less page:
http://less2css.org/

Try pasting it in (without your <---line 12) and you will see it works.
MAybe you are using some javastript that interacts with the less script on your page.

**Edit:**
You also have an semicolon at the end that breaks older versions (<=1.3.1) of the less parser.
If I take it out it parses well through al versions ... and I do not manage to reproduce your error.

Comment: I tried this and received the same error.

I also tried defining the colours as variables but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I dunno, tried your exact code in many ways now on less ... and it seems to work for me. I am sorry ... I am not able to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Martin, I cannot reproduce your error using your code above and the compiler at http://less2css.org/. The only ways I can reproduce a syntax error message on line 12 are:

1. Remove the colon after the `background-color` property.
2. Add some non-comment related characters after the end semi-colon (like your note `<--- line 12` is invalid, but I'm sure you put that in for illustration above).
3. Add an end quote after either (a) the color, (b) the percentage, or (c) the parenthesis.  An example of (b) - `100%'`. There may be some other characters that would cause it too, but some just print right out into the css wihtout a syntax error.
4. A character separated by a space or other invalid character for a property name before the property name, like `y background-color` or `*background-color`.

Obviously, none of those exist in your code shown above, but you might double check that your actual code does not have some extra characters or missing characters that might be causing the issue.